# Bounded convergence theorem with filtrations

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-expectation, filtrations

Suppose in a filtered probability space $(\Omega,\mathbb{P},\{\mathcal{F}_n\},\mathcal{F})$ we have a sequence of almost surely vanishing adapted random variables $\varepsilon_n$. By the conditional bounded convergence theorem $\mathbb{E}_{\mathcal{G}}(e^{it\varepsilon_{n+1}}-1)\longrightarrow 0$ almost surely for any $\mathcal{G}\subset\mathcal{F}$. Does this implies also that $\mathbb{E}_{\mathcal{F}_n}(e^{it\varepsilon_{n+1}}-1)\longrightarrow 0$? I feel like it should, tried to prove it using $\mathcal{F}_\infty=\sigma\left(\bigcup_{n=0}^\infty\mathcal{F}_n\right)$, but could not get anywhere... Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: This follows from theorem 4.6.10 on page 248 of https://services.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/PTE5_011119.pdf

Comment: thank you so much, it is exactly the kind of thing I was trying to obtain! Gotta read this book